# Node how to pass file to http.write method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I woudl like to print file to `res.write()` method but I get error:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
```

My code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var http = require("http");


http.createServer(function (req, res){

    res.write(getData());
    res.end();

}).listen(3333);


function getData(){
    fs.readFile('testfs.txt', function(err, data){

        if(err)
        {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
        }else {
            console.log(data.toString());
            return data.toString();
        }

    });
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You did terribly because you didn't do your function asynchronous and that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: How to correct this?

Comment: There has to be a callback. I'll write an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.write` didn't get string nor buffer because your function `getData` wasn't asynchronous. Here's the fix I hope will solve your problem:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res){

    getData(function(data){
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    }));

}).listen(3333);

function getData(cb){
    fs.readFile('testfs.txt', function(err, data){

        if(err)
        {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
        }else {
            cb(data.toString());
        }

    });
}
```

Where `cb` argument is a callback function obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html):

```
const http = require('http');
const fs   = require('fs');

http.createServer((req, res) => {

  fs.createReadStream('testfs.txt')
    .on('error', (e) => {
      console.log('Error:', e);
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.end();
    })
    .pipe(res)


}).listen(3333);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around; just call getData and pass in response, then when the file is loaded, call response.end(string).